# PowerShell Write-Host append to line instead of new line?

Tags: powershell

I'm parsing an external log file `auditlog_0.txt` and want to pull out only selected strings and have them placed on one single line, preferably in either tab (`` `t ``) delimited or some other delimited manner (comma/colon/semicolon).  I have the code working where it puts each output on a new line but due to size of file I can only get 9999 lines in buffer and have to break up my source file into 3 parts to fit the output.

I've inherited this code and have been researching `-NoNewline` but seems no matter what format I put it into it doesn't work.

```
$myFileLines = gc .\auditlog_0.txt

foreach ($line in $myFileLines) {
    if ($line -like '* Sequence*') {
        $auditlog = $line
    } else  {
        if ($line -like '*Time*') {
            Write-Host $auditlog $line
        } else  {
            if ($line -like '*Cluster*') {
                Write-Host $auditlog `t `t `t `t `t `t $line
            } else  {
                if ($line -like '*Action*') {
                    Write-Host $auditlog `t `t `t `t `t `t `t `t `t `t `t `t $line
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above gives me exactly what I'm looking for, but only on 3 separate lines (and nicely tab indented), so now I just need to figure out how to get it all appended onto a single line.

Comment: instead of outputting the lines via `Write-Host` ... why don't you ADD them to the `$AuditLog` variable? then you could write the accumulated values out as one line ... [*grin*]

Comment: Like @Lee_Dailey suggested, I usually build up my text in a variable and then write to console. That is only if this text is not necessary as tracing.